# Can't Get Android Native Access

Tags: android, native, codenameone

Tried using native access to implement a bluetooth functionality in android but on starting the app on a device it seems the native access variable is null. Need help in figuring out why it happened and how to solve it. Thanks

These are my build hints
[image]

An example of usage in StateMachine class

```
    BTNative nativeBT = (BTNative)NativeLookup.create(BTNative.class);
@Override
protected void onMain_ScanButtonAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
    super.onMain_ScanButtonAction(c, event);
    try {

        if (nativeBT != null && nativeBT.isSupported()) {

            try {
                nativeBT.findBT();
                nativeBT.openBT();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Dialog.show("Error", "Exception during findBT and openBT access: " + t, "OK", null);
            }
        }else{
            Dialog.show("Error", "Can't get native access", "OK", null);
        }

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Dialog.show("Error", "Exception during native access: " + t, "OK", null);
    }
}
```

NativeImpl

```
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.UUID;
    import android.widget.Toast;
```

public class BTNativeImpl{

```
//android built in classes for bluetooth operations
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

//needed for communication to bluetooth device / network
OutputStream mmOutputStream;
InputStream mmInputStream;
Thread workerThread;

byte[] readBuffer;
int readBufferPosition;
volatile boolean stopWorker;



public void closeBT() {
    try {
        stopWorker = true;
        mmOutputStream.close();
        mmInputStream.close();
        mmSocket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//this will send text data to be printed by the bluetooth printer
public void sendData(String param){
    try {
        // the text typed by the user
        param += "\n";
        mmOutputStream.write(param.getBytes());
        // tell the user data were sent
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//this will find a bluetooth printer device
public void findBT() {

    try {
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {

          Toast.makeText(com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity(), "No bluetooth adapter available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity().startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
        }

        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                if (device.getName().equals("BlueTooth Printer")) {
                    mmDevice = device;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity(), "Bluetooth device found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void openBT() {
    try {
        //Standard SerialPortService ID
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
        mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
        mmSocket.connect();
        mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
        mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();
        beginListenForData();
        Toast.makeText(com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity(), "Bluetooth Opened", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void beginListenForData() {
    try {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        //this is the ASCII code for a newline character
        final byte delimiter = 10;
        stopWorker = false;
        readBufferPosition = 0;
        readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker) {
                    try {
                        int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();

                        if (bytesAvailable > 0) {

                            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                            for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                                byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                if (b == delimiter) {

                                    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                    // specify US-ASCII encoding
                                    final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                    readBufferPosition = 0;

                                    // tell the user data were sent to bluetooth printer device
                                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                          Toast.makeText(com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity(), data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        stopWorker = true;
                    }

                }
            }
        });

        workerThread.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean isSupported() {
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely also need BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission. I'm not sure if that is the only issue, but definitely would cause problems.

From Android's developer guide:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#Permissions

You also made a big mistake in changing the inheritance of the impl class to derive `Activity`!

You need to create a separate activity class and register it separately as we create the impl class and Android creates the activity class and both are different. I suggest looking at other cn1libs most of which are open source to see how this was done. I also suggest connecting your device with a cable and viewing output in ddms to track issues.

Comment: I added a couple of additional insights

Comment: @JamesH@ShaiAlmog I tried what you suggested by using **com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity()** and not extending **Activity** but now nothing happens when I click the button to connect. I looked into the ddms and found that bluetooth permission was denied(as in the app doesnt have bluetooth permission). But i have included the permissions too..

Comment: @JamesH@ShaiAlmog Also on installing the app i dont see the bluetooth permissions.

Comment: Even if you delete any previously installed versions, and then install it, the install screen doesn't mention permissions?

Comment: @JamesH Just fixed it. I used xpermission instead of xpermissions. Thanks